# What are pros & cons of naming in game currency a standard name vs a gimmick?

Tags: monetization

We're creating a store and going to add an in game currency. We did a poll and Tokens & Sheep were the top options selected by the players.

I personally think Sheep would be more fun like a barter system as well as it is an in game resource as you may know from the Settlers of Catan (my game https://colonist.io/)

I know that https://starve.io/ has Golden Bread and https://surviv.io/ has Potato as in game currency.

Are there any other such examples? What are the pros cons of such naming?

I don't know any big games which do such a thing.

Comment: It sounds like you already have a favoured solution that you think could work, but you're doubting your judgement and looking for permission from strangers to proceed. You don't need our permission. You and your players know better what works for your game than we do. I'd recommend that you trust your instincts, try the design you like best, and worst case? Be ready to patch with a new name in case the sky falls (but it probably won't ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One problem with using sheep or potatoes as your currency is that it is a bit unintuitive for the player. They might be unsure that this resource is really used *only* as a currency and doesn't fulfill any other mechanical purposes.

When you give the player a sheep, they will wonder what to do with it. Their first ideas will likely be to try to slaughter it for meat or shear it for wool. Or perhaps milk it of sheep's milk? Maybe it's a pet they have to care for? Perhaps they can ride on it? Perhaps it can be combat-trained and used as a companion in battle?

Trading it for other resources would be pretty low on their list of potential uses.

And then there is of course the plausibility problem. A resource which anyone can produce, which is perishable and which isn't perfectly [fungible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fungibility) would not make for a very good currency in the real world. But that is of course an issue which can be handwaved away when this resource doesn't have any of these properties in *your* game.

But players will get over that eventually after spending some time with the game.  Especially when you make sure your UI design and the tutorial make it clear that sheep are really just a currency and nothing else. So it's really not that much of a problem.